# How to make a foreign key on a different account

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

So I am currently using my account with username: ctxsys and a password
In this account I have table named `archiv11`.

In another account named `d5a11` with a password I have a table called `fileLocation` and what I am trying to do to make a foreign key from my current account table to the location table.

```
create table archiv11(
 id integer primary key,
 fileName varchar2(50),
 fileContent blob,
 locationID integer,
 CONSTRAINT archivFK FOREIGN KEY(locationID) REFERENCES d5a11.fileLocation(loc_ID)
);
```

I get the error the table fileLocation does not exsist.

Is this possible?

Comment: You need read access to the table in order to define a foreign key relationship to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem; owner of the referenced table has to grant `REFERENCE` to another user, which has to precede referenced table name with its owner.

Here's an example: user `MIKE` has a table whose `ID` is to be referenced in `SCOTT`'s table

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> create table mike_table (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> grant references on mike_table to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table scott_table (id number primary key,
  2                            id_mike number constraint fk_scmi references mike.mike_table(id)
  3                           );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. However you must permit it with

```
grant reference on d5a11.fileLocation to ctxsys;
```